# Where this undefined in Express.js console is coming from?

Tags: node.js, express, undefined, middleware

Useless middleware for testing purposes:

```
module.exports = function () {
    return function rankick(req, res, next) {
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            return next('Random kick...');
        }

        next();
    };
};
```

Injected into a simple express app:

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path')
    rankick= require('./rankick'),
    util = require('util');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(rankick()); // Using the middleware

if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.end('Hello World!');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'));
```

When `next()` is invoked with the error string, console logs `undefined` followed by the `500` error:

```
undefined
GET / 500 28ms
GET / 200 4ms
undefined
GET / 500 5ms
```

Comment: The `require('path')` bit is silly. It's being used for only one of the `__dirname` lines. Probably not necessary as all it is doing is adding a '/' or '\' depending on your os, which won't change in production. Just my 2c

Answer (score 1):

Is it's this line in the [errorHandler middleware](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/errorHandler.js#L48). Maybe it expects to get a new Error('Random kick..')?

It's been a while since I used to default errorHandler so I am not 100% sure. In case it's not downvote and I'll remove this answer.

Answer (score -1):

You should do

```
module.exports = function rankick(req, res, next) {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        console.log('Random kick...');
    }
    else
        next();
};
```

Don't use return to pass the function. `module.exports` is the object that is passed when require is called.

Also `next()` is supposed to be called if you want to continue processing to next middleware. If you want to stop processing/kick request don't call `next()`

Comment: Loot at favicon middleware http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/favicon.html `next(err)` is used.

Comment: `next(err)` is error handling, where you are pass the errors for next middleware. If you are just kicking them randomly, then no need for that.